# Probability combinatorics deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Edit: Sorry for not providing more on this question the first time. I tried to solve it.

When choosing 13 cards from a deck of 52 cards, what is the probability of choosing precisely a card with a number 6,7,8 of the same suit? For example a 6,7,8 of heart  or a 6,7,8 of diamonds, or a 6,7,8 of spades, or a 6,7,8 of clubs. All three cards must be the numbers of 6,7,8 and only of a single suit. These must be among the hand of  13 cards.

My first thoughts on this question that I only have 4 possibilities of this happening for the entire deck of 52 cards. So I thought $(_4 C_1)(_{13}C _{3})$ will account for the possible number of decks that will include cards of 6,7,8 of all the same suit out of 13 cards in the hand.

And $(_{52} C_{13})$ gives me all the possible combinations of 13 cards from 52 cards.  So this probability that I got would be:
$\frac{(_4 C_1)(_{13}C _{3})}{(_{52} C_{13})}\approx 5*10^{-7}$. However I feel something is off.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: What do you mean by $6,7,8$ ? Do you mean the ranks $6\;or7\;or\;8$ or the number of cards $6,7,8$. Also, are they $3$ separate problems, the commas create ambiguity.

Comment: Answer posted below. Your thoughts are in the right direction but there are a few things to take care of. There are ${4 \choose 1}$ possibilities to choose the suit, and then you will have $3$ of your cards fixed, so you will need to choose the remaining $10$ from the rest of the $49$ remaining cards, i.e., ${49 \choose 10}$. However, you are double counting some cases where you have 6,7, 8 from two or more suits; so you need to deduct them, but then you will have deducted all cases with 3 or more suits so you will need to add them, etc, etc, which will lead to the answer I posted below.

Comment: Thank you all for your insight. I really appreciate it your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer follows the inclusion-exclusion principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):
\begin{equation}
P = \frac{{4 \choose 1} \times {49 \choose 10} - {4 \choose 2} \times {46 \choose 7} + {4 \choose 3} \times {43 \choose 4} - {4 \choose 4} \times {40 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 13}}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Total number of outcomes = ${52\choose13}\times(13!)$ [Since, we choose 13 cards]

Now, we calculate the total number of favorable outcomes. Essentially, what we are going to calculate is the number of arrangements of 13 cards such that any 3 cards are 6,7,8 of the same suit

Note : There may be arrangements where there are more than one suit which have all 6,7,8. In other words, a arrangement may have 6,7,8 of Hearts and also 6,7,8 of Spades. So, we must be cautious of over-counting.

***Case I*** : There is only suit containing 6,7,8 in the arrangement.

Number of ways to choose that one suit = ${4\choose1}$. Also, now we cannot choose 6,7,8 of the other 3 suits. Thus, out of the 13 cards, 3 have been chosen and the rest (10) of the cards can be chosen from (52-12) = 40 options[These 12 cards are the 6,7,8 of the 4 suits]. Number of ways to choose the rest of the cards = $40\choose10$. Now, we need to arrange the 13 cards. This can be done in $13!$ ways.

$\therefore$ the number of arrangements in this Case = ${4\choose1}\times{40\choose10}\times13!$

***Case II*** : There are exactly 2 suits containing 6,7,8 in the arrangement.

Number of ways to choose 2 suits = ${4\choose2} = 6$. Also, now we cannot choose 6,7,8 of the other 2 suits. Thus, out of the 13 cards, 6 have been chosen and the rest (7) of the cards can be chosen from (52-12) = 40 options[These 12 cards are the 6,7,8 of the 4 suits]. Number of ways to choose the rest of the cards = $40\choose7$. Now, we need to arrange the 13 cards. This can be done in $13!$ ways.

$\therefore$ the number of arrangements in this Case = ${4\choose2}\times{40\choose7}\times13!$

***Case III*** : There are exactly 3 suits containing 6,7,8 in the arrangement.

Number of ways to choose 3 suits = ${4\choose3} = 6$. Also, now we cannot choose 6,7,8 of the remaining 1 suit. Thus, out of the 13 cards, 9 have been chosen and the rest (4) of the cards can be chosen from (52-12) = 40 options[These 12 cards are the 6,7,8 of the 4 suits]. Number of ways to choose the rest of the cards = $40\choose4$. Now, we need to arrange the 13 cards. This can be done in $13!$ ways.

$\therefore$ the number of arrangements in this Case = ${4\choose3}\times{40\choose4}\times13!$

***Case IV*** : There are 4 suits containing 6,7,8 in the arrangement.

This is the easiest case. Among the 13 cards, 12 are already chosen and the number of ways to choose the 13th card is (52-12) = 40 ways. Now, we need to arrange the 13 cards. This can be done in $13!$ ways.

$\therefore$ the number of arrangements in this Case = $40\times(13!)$ = ${4\choose4}\times{40\choose1}\times13!$

Therefore, after adding up all the cases, the number of favorable outcomes
$ = {4\choose1}\times{40\choose10}\times13! + {4\choose2}\times{40\choose7}\times13! + {4\choose3}\times{40\choose4}\times13! + {4\choose4}\times{40\choose1}\times13!$

$ = 13!\times(4\times847660528 + 6\times18643560 + 4\times91390 + 1\times40) = 3502869072\times(13!)$

$\therefore$ the required probability = (Total number of favorable outcomes)/(Total number of outcomes) = $(3502869072\times13!)/(635013559600\times13!) = \frac{218929317}{39688347475} = 0.005516(approx)$