# What is the probability of drawing a $6,7,8$ in a hand of $13$ cards from a deck of $52$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I am investigating a game called Rummy Royale. If I set the number of players to $3$, then I can split the deck of $52$ cards into $4$ hands of $13$ cards each.

When choosing $13$ cards from a deck of $52$ cards, what is the probability of choosing precisely the cards with the numbers $6,7,8$ of the same suit? For example a $6,7,8$ of heart  or a $6,7,8$ of diamonds, or a $6,7,8$ of spades, or a $6,7,8$ of clubs. All three cards must be the numbers of $6,7,8$ and only of a single suit. These must be among the hand of  $13$ cards.

My first thoughts on this question that I only have $4$ possibilities of this happening for the entire deck of $52$ cards. So I thought $(_4 C_1)(_{13}C _{3})$ will account for the possible number of decks that will include cards of $6,7,8$ of all the same suit out of $13$ cards in the hand.

And $(_{52} C_{13})$ gives me all the possible combinations of 13 cards from 52 cards.  So this probability that I got would be:
$\frac{(_4 C_1)(_{13}C _{3})}{(_{52} C_{13})}\approx 5*10^{-7}$. However I feel something is off. I haven't done probability in over a decade.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please do not ask the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4106531/probability-combinatorics-deck-of-cards) twice.  Instead, edit the original question.  Questions which are closed may be reopened after proper context is added.

Comment: Sorry about that. I truly believed that when a question was closed, it was closed for good.

Comment: Seems you have a pretty good answer there: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4106611/116591  I didn't check/verify all the details but the idea of this answer is the right one.

Comment: I feel like I need to account for the other 10 cards in the hand of 13. I am not sure though if I should or even how.

Comment: You have not taken care of the fact that 6,7,8 of some other suit(s) may also occur.